# spring boot database insert not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with my spring boot configuration in xml I created this configuration :

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" primary="true" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:20300:test"/>
        <property name="username" value="test"/>
        <property name="password" value="test"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
     <bean id="entityManagerFactory" primary="true" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="model.entity"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="msPersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  />
    <bean id="controllerService"
        class="...impl.ControllerServiceImpl">
        <property name="entityManager" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

And I had the java code like this :

```
public void setEntityManager(final HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManager) {
        final RepositoryFactorySupport factorySupport = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager.createEntityManager());

        controlRepository = factorySupport.getRepository(ObjControlRepository.class);
}
```

when i'm using find method it's ok, but when I'm doing a save, there are not exception but the value it's not insert.
Thank your for your help.

[Edit]
To save I'm using :

```
/**
 * The Interface ObjControlRepository.
 */
public interface ObjControlRepository extends CrudRepository<ObjControl, String> {

}
```

And I'm calling the method like that :

```
controlRepository.save(newValue);
```

Comment: Can you add the code used to insert

Comment: are you using @Transactional annotation in your code?

Comment: No I'm not using @Transactional annotation in my code.

Comment: and what does the LOG say?

Comment: 2017-03-09 11:39:08.743  INFO 12644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.o.a.b.c.impl.ControllerServiceImpl     : save

Answer (score 0):

You should try to explicitly set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` variable to `auto`. This will prevent your application to release previous data when you start your application.

[You can learn more about the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto variable here.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use transactions and commit the transaction in order to save an entity.

So Use `@Transactionl` annotation on your service layer, like this:

```
@Transactional
public class ControllerServiceImpl {
...
}
```

As `ControllerServiceImpl` is already declared as a bean in spring configuration file, Spring will take care about committing the transaction once you save an entity.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it's change nothing. Sincerely

Comment: @Pilou, may be you need to add more code for us to understand where can be the issue. What is the package for the `@Transactional` you are using?